# Display the combinations and the number of combinations without the same value of the two array

Tags: java, arrays, combinations

I need to create a function that will accept two arrays of integers. Display the combinations and the number of combinations without the same value.

Example:

```
Array 1 = { 1, 2, 3 }; 
Array 2 = { 2, 3, 4 };
```

Output :

```
1,2
1,3
1,4
2,3
2,4
3,2
3,4
```

Combination count : `7`

I've seen a lot of complicated codes here and can't find the exact goal that I am looking for so far, While waiting for someone to help I will just keep browsing and searching. Also I'm using Java 7.

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: `for (int a : arr1) for (int b : arr2) if (a != b) System.out.println(a + "," + b);`

Comment: It can be very hard to discover the right name for a mathematical operation. What you're describing is called the 'Cartesian product' of your two arrays, with some results filtered out. The term 'combinations' has a very specific meaning in math: It refers to an unordered selection of items from a single set that has distinct elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

Note: This code is considering given example. There are no validation done.     You can add it if needed.

```
int count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
                if(array[i] != array2[j]){
                    System.out.println("Combination "+array[i]+" "+array2[j]);
                    count = count +1;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Combination "+count);
```